# MEMBER OF with array_values AND operator

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder, dql

there is my problem :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p as post')
            ->where(':tags MEMBER OF p.tags')
            ->setParameter('tags', array_values($tagArray))
            ->orderBy('p.postedAt', 'DESC')
            ->setFirstResult($start)
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
```

With this code, I can retrieve all posts that have as tags those present in $tagArray.
But for example if we have this dataset:

post1 with tag1, tag2 and tag3

post 2 with tag1, tag3, tag4

Currently if I search with tag1, tag2 I will get this result:

post1 and post2.

How can I get only post1? MEMBER OF seems to make the condition sound like tag1 OR tag2, would there be a way to do a tag1 AND tag2 ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: You can try `->getSql();` after `->getQuery()` to check how Doctrine transforms `MEMBER OF` to SQL, then I think you can create new query using it.

Comment: Thank you, in the end I made a SQL query that works, but there's no way to do what I would like directly in DQL?